# Use DependencyProperty in the Style

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have TemplatedControl with Dependency Property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Color", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(MenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush)));

public SolidColorBrush Color
{
   get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
}
```

In the style I want to use this property to set Background. I tried:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MenuButton" x:Name="MenuButtonSimple">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

and

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MenuButton" x:Name="MenuButtonSimple">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Color}"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

If I set fixed color in the template - it works:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MenuButton" x:Name="MenuButtonSimple">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="667788"/>
```

How can I use dependency property (Color) in the style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a CustomControl named MenuButton.cs:

In the Generic.xaml I have:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Color}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you see TemplateBinding Color, nothing complex like in user control, and then:

```
public class MenuButton : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Color", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(MenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    static MenuButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MenuButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MenuButton)));
    }
}
```

I put the brush to red just for testing, NOTE I did for WPF.

In case you need it outside the template, this works:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Indeed I added

```
<Setter Property="Color" Value="Orange"/>
```

and works changing the background like a charm.

Comment: Yes, it works for me to use dependency property inside `<Setter Property="Template">`, but my task is to use this property outside it.  For example, for `<Setter Property="Background">`

Comment: Just add `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Color}"/>` right after `<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">`, but before `<Setter Property="Template">` to see what I am talking about

Comment: would you take a look to the binding I added for outside a template?